# i want to customize [maxYAxisTickLength]="23" value base on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there any way to customize maxYAxisTickLength value base on screen sizes in ngx bar chart Angular

```
<ng-container *ngIf="chartType === 'HORIZONTAL'">
  <div class="horizontal-bar-chart">
    <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="chartData"
      [xAxis]="true"
      [yAxis]="true"
      [maxYAxisTickLength]="23"
      [barPadding]="20"
    >
    </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```